# How to feed physical dimensions of robot to navigation stack?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, transform-broadcaster, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just successfully finished my simulation and just assembled my robot hardware. Now i want to setup navigation stack in my real robot.

In the simulation, the navigation stack will take the dimensions of robot (Base L x W x H, wheel dia, Wheel separation) from the spawned URDF file but how and where should i feed these details to navigations stack in the real robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242585/how-to-feed-physical-dimensions-of-robot-to-navigation-stack?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, the URDF file is not only used by simulator(e.g. Gazebo), but also used by RViz, which can display a robot model after reading the URDF file.

As for navigation stack, the URDF file doesn't affect the navigation. The local and global planner are setup by several configuration files(costmap_common_params.yaml, global_costmap_params.yaml, local_costmap_params.yaml and base_local_planner_params.yaml). The robot footprint is setup in the `costmap_common_params.yaml`.

For more details, you can see [navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup).

---

EDIT

It is not necessary to spawn the URDF, it doesn't affect the navigation. RViz can display a robot outline according to the parameters(footprint or robot_radius) in `costmap_common_params.yaml`. But with URDF, RViz can also display a good-looking robot model. It just for good-looking.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-08-30**:
So, should i spawn the URDF file while experimenting ROS navigation in real robot also?

**Comment by [Abderrahmane](https://answers.ros.org/users/60317/abderrahmane/) on 2020-10-01**:
how can I get the footprint of a robot model build with meshes ??